# OpenLayers 3, map.on('moveend',..): Differentiate between user interaction and map.setCenter() calling

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gps, event-listener

I am implementing OpenLayers for a GIS application and want to add a 20 seconds timeout when the user scrolled the map, after which the GPS auto track function should resume.

For that I am utilizing the map.on('moveend', move_func(..)) listener. The problem is that it cannot differentiate whether the user scrolled or the position change came from map.setCenter(..).
Although I could implement a state variable which is set to true every time map.setCenter() is called, this does not only seem inelegant but also wrong in case the setCenter call and a user interaction would overlap.

So is there any better solution to this?